# problem save with checkboxes on devise registration user

Tags: ruby, checkbox, devise, save, registration

When I am in local /users/sign_up, I added a checkboxes type field so that the user can select game categories. When I am in my console, the creation of a user is done correctly by selecting my categories in my "favorites_games" array.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-07-10 16:20:48 
+0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>. 
{"email"=>"jujuju@mail.fr", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "favorites_games"=>["", 
"Dessin", "Stratégie", "Réflexion"]}, "commit"=>"Deviens 
 membre"}
 Unpermitted parameter: :favorites_games. Context: { 
 controller: Devise::RegistrationsController, action: create, 
 request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x000000011032ef90>, 
 params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>. 
 {"email"=>"jujuju@mail.fr", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "favorites_games"=>["", 
 "Dessin", "Stratégie", "Réflexion"]}, "commit"=>"Deviens 
 membre", "controller"=>"devise/registrations", 
 "action"=>"create"} }
 TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE 
 "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "jujuju@mail.fr"], 
 ["LIMIT", 1]]
 TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
 Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within 
 layouts/application
 Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | 
 Allocations: 79)
 Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within 
 layouts/application (Duration: 3.5ms | Allocations: 7174)
 Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | 
 Allocations: 151)
 Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | 
 Allocations: 24)
 Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 9.2ms 
 | Allocations: 15901)
 Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 281ms (Views: 9.4ms | 
 ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 21547)`
```

When I'm on my sign_up page locally, when I select my categories by clicking on my checkboxes, it doesn't save. It tells me "favorites games can't be blank" and I see that an empty string is inserted before my category selections and that causes a rollback in my server.

```
`def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save && user.favorites_games[0] == ""
  @user.favorites_games.delete_at(0)
  redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'Profil créé 
 ✔️'
 else
  render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
 end`

 private

 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, 
  :username, :age, :city, :email, :password, 
  :password_confirmation, favorites_games: [], :photo)
  end
 end
```

I tried to insert in the create and new method in the users controller, a method to delete the first index of the favorites_games array.

I also tried in my strong params, to write in two ways the argument `favorites_games ==>:favorites_games` and `favorites_games: []`.

In my User model, I tried to insert in my validations:

```
validates:favorites_games, allow_blank, inclusion {in:Event::CATEGORIES}
```

In my `html.erb` file, I tried to put `mulitple: true` as well as `include_hidden: true` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not link screenshots but copy'n'paste relevant code fragments to you question.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Do try and trim down the code to only the relevant part. We can't read everything.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I'm new to the platform